Downloading a file shared via Onedrive using SharePoint API
I have a file stored & shared with me using SharePoint. The link of the file is as follows:
https://<org-name>-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/<email>/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx

Is it possible to download this file using the SharePoint API like a file stored in a normal SharePoint site?
https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<path-here>')

Microsoft Graph API can be used alternatively but I want to know if it is possible via SharePoint API as well.
